# vector field for 2nd order differential eq.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

This is a real exam question I was not able to solve:

Draw the vector field corrsponding to the differential equation:

$m\ddot{x} = -\omega^2x + \gamma \dot{x} + f(t)$

What's so odd about this is that this is a 2nd order differential equation. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Convert it to a pair of first order equations by introducing $y = \dot{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $n^{th}$ order diﬀerential equation can be converted into an $n-$dimensional system  of first order  differential equations.

We have:

- $x_1 = x$
- $x'_1 = x' = x_2$
- $x'_2 = x'' = \dfrac{1}{m} (-\omega^2x + \gamma~ x' + f(t)) = \dfrac{1}{m} (-\omega^2 x_1 + \gamma~ x_2 + f(t))$

Our reduced system is:

$$\begin{aligned}
x'_1 & = x_2 \\
x'_2 & = \dfrac{1}{m} (-\omega^2~ x_1 + \gamma~ x_2 + f(t)) 
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: that helps, thanks a lot!